# Selecting multiple rows into a single row temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp

What I am trying to do is select multiple rows into a single row of a temp table. There should be 1 row in the temp table listing all of the different accrual values. Here is the code below:

```
    declare @RunDate varchar(7)
set @RunDate = '2013-07'

declare @ShortItemNo1 int

set @ShortItemNo1 = 723639




declare @SalesAccruals table(QuantityShipped int, ShortItemNo int, GrossAmount money, AccrualReturns money, AccrualMedicaid money,
                            AccrualChargebacks money)

insert @SalesAccruals

select
    sum(s.QuantityShipped) QuantityShipped,
    s.ShortItemNo,
    sum(s.ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
    case when aa.AccrualType=3 then sum(a.AccrualAmount) end,
    case when aa.AccrualType=8 then sum(a.AccrualAmount) end,
    case when aa.AccrualType=2 then sum(a.AccrualAmount) end
from
    SalesSummary s join Accruals a on
        s.SalesSummaryGuid = a.SalesSummaryGuid
    join AccrualsSetup aa on
        a.AccrualsSetupGuid = aa.AccrualsSetupGuid
    join LookupAccrualTypes la on
        la.AccrualTypeID = aa.AccrualType

where
    convert(varchar(7), InvoiceDate, 20) = @RunDate
    and s.ShortItemNo in (@ShortItemNo1)
group by
    s.ShortItemNo,
    aa.AccrualType

select * from @SalesAccruals
```

Comment: Can you give sample data for what you want in the temp table?

Comment: right now the select statement is returning four rows because there are four different accrual types. I want one row with all of the accrual types to be selected into the temp table. I am not sure if a case statement is the best way to go about this...

Comment: Right now it works the way I want, but the other values in the columns are null values. Any way to get rid of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `SELECT` part of your query to be this...

```
select
    sum(s.QuantityShipped) QuantityShipped,
    s.ShortItemNo,
    sum(s.ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
    sum(case when aa.AccrualType=3 then a.AccrualAmount else 0 end),
    sum(case when aa.AccrualType=8 then a.AccrualAmount else 0 end),
    sum(case when aa.AccrualType=2 then a.AccrualAmount else 0 end)
```

Then remove `aa.AccrualType` from the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you my friend.